# Twitter JSON API in Android Development

Tags: java, android, json, http, twitter

I Started working on Android Development for a while now. According to the tutorials im following im trying to retireve JSON info from the Twitter API...

As it was instructed in the tutorial, this is the code to use:

"http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=**write the username**"

HOWEVER, i got a response saying that the API is no longer available and i should migrate to API v1.1.

Could anyone please help on what to do to replace the url i was instructed to use??

**NOTE**
When i used the new url from API v1.1 : "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=twitterapi&count=2"

i get the following:

"{"errors":[{"message":"Bad Authentication data","code":215}]}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old Twitter API did not require Authentication for retrieving `user_timeline`, but v1.1 requires authentication to retrieve data(https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline). According to Twitter API document user authentication is required for all the API v1.1 requests.

You can read more about authentication here
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth#v1-1

Comment: Ive tried understanding the link of authentication... yet i cant grasp the concept of what to include in the URL or how should i change it in order to retrieve info...
could u plz provide an example?
Thanks

Comment: @Tharwat You need to implement Twitter OAuth in your application, there are various oauth implementations available. One of the popular is `twitter4j.org/en/`. You need to sign your request once you implement OAuth.

Comment: sorry for replying late but thank you for your help everything works now